# Python - is finally block necessary in socket operation?

Tags: python, sockets

I am a newbie to Python and currently doing some socket development. I am not very sure about the best practices of Python socket programming.

For example, in the following code, are the `conn=None` line and the `finally` block necessary? What is the best convention for this kind of operation?

```
@post('/relay/')
def relay():
    conn = None  # Do I need this line to ensure conn not to be undefined?
    try:
        conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        conn.connect(host_port)
        conn.sendall(content)
    except socket.error, se:
        if se.errno == 61:
            logger.error(...)
        else:
            logger.error(...)
        abort(400, 'Error...')
    finally:   # Should this socket.close() task be in finally block? like Java?
        if conn:
            conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            conn.close()
    return ''
```

Comment: If your code exits after what you show us, the socket is closed automatically.

Comment: In fact, it's in a @post("...") function of a Bottle app, I want to relay the request payload to another server.

Comment: @Tichodroma If the whole *process* exists, maybe, but if you mean the function returning, no, not really. It *often* works in CPython, but it's bad style because it fails whenever there are reference cycles or if you use any Python other than the reference implementation.

Comment: Also if you use the `with` statement you don't need to close the socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`finally` is typically used when you are working with some kind of connection (socket, database, etc) that is open, being operated on in the `try` and *no matter what happens*, should be closed after.

So yes, `conn.close()` should go in the `finally` block.

As for the `conn=None`, that could be required, but in your case it's not. Because if

```
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

fails, `conn` is never defined and it jumps to the `finally` block (because of the failure). However you check for `if conn=None` so it won't complain about trying to close a connection that is not defined because the `if` is skipped.

Comment: Agreed. There is a more concrete example in https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example which handles `socket.socket()`, `connect()` exception separately. But It seems the point is once the socket is created (i.e. not `None`), you could/should close it no matter if there was an exception.

Comment: BTW, `Sockets are automatically closed when they are garbage-collected` according to the doc above.

Comment: Even so it's good practice to close stuff in the finally block. You don't want to depend on the GC. What if you want to reuse `conn` somewhere else?